# If i mirror an image with the canvas multiple times, why does the image lose quality?

Tags: image, canvas

```
mirror() {
    const mirrorCanvas = document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const clientRect = this.parentRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = this.imageBase64;
    image.onload = () => {
        mirrorCanvas.width = clientRect.width;
        mirrorCanvas.height = clientRect.height;
        const ctx = mirrorCanvas.getContext('2d');
        if (ctx) {
            ctx.scale(1, -1);
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, clientRect.width, clientRect.height);

            this.imageBase64 = (mirrorCanvas.toDataURL(`image/${this.format}`, 1));

        }
    }
}
```

I have this code, which mirrors the image.

However if i keep mirroring this image, it will lose quality, even if i set the quality to 1.

Why is that?

Comment: I assume this is because a canvas element represents images as bitmap/raster and not as vector graphics.  Repeated manipulation of a bitmap is likely to degrade it unless you know for sure that each and every step is not lossy.  And I can't tell from that code if it is or not because it doesn't constitute a [mcve].  For example, what is the image you're using?  What is `this.format`?  What rendering engine are you talking about?  You might consider making a standalone example on codepen/stackblitz/etc and linking to it, if you want a better answer than "bitmaps degrade".

Comment: Hmm, yes I understand what you mean, This is copied from our project and this.format is just the the format or type (jpg, png, ...) of the image that is being mirrored. It is supposed to work with any image. That's why i didn't really give a specific example. I think i will just store the mirrored image in a variable and switch between original and mirrored, so that it only loses quality ones.

Comment: What do you mean with rendering engine? I'm working in a canvas, so I think i'm using the default rendering engine of the canvas, but are there others I can use?

Comment: That depends on the browser, so the answer will depend on where it's running.  There are css properties like [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) which may have an impact on what algorithm is used to do `ctx.scale(1, -1)`.  The idea to just store the original image makes sense.

Comment: Okay, great. This was helpful, thanks!